# Sphinx Search Sorting/Ranking

Tags: php, full-text-search, geocoding, sphinx

I just recently discovered sphinx search which I want to use for my PHP application. I have a table of geolocations where every record stores a country code. For every user who uses the search function to look up geopositions, I know which country he is from.

How would I reweigh the results such that the matching results are ascending in distance to the country of the user? I already have calculated a distance matrix for each country to each other, which I can access via SQL. The country information in the geolocation database is stored as 2 letter ISO country code.

What is a good solution for this problem? I heard about UDFs, are they applicable for that problem? Is it possible to solve this problem more easily by reformatting my table?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easiest" way to solve this is to have coordinates for each country. You then store the coordinates for each record in the sphinx index, and when searching find the coordinates and us it in the search. This way sphinx caculates the distance dynamically.

Did you have coordinates likes this to create the matrix? But it also resupposes, you are just using a 'point' per country, if your matrix is more advanced, eg taking the closest point on the borders of each (to make disances between odd shaped countries better), then it wont work so well.

In theory you could perhaps do this with [payloads](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-joined-field),  by using the country name as keywords, and the distance in a payload (arranged specially so that close disances have a high weight) but will probably be expensive to index, and might not work all that well in practice.

Comment: I think storing the coordinates (like central point) of each country is a good idea. Would i use GEODIST for the ordering by distance then?

Comment: yes. Use Geodist to compute the distance as a virtual attribute, and then just order by it

Comment: I am not that familiar with virtual attributes: So something like "SELECT name, GEODIST(x,y) AS d WHERE MATCH(...) ORDER BY d"?

Comment: Ah yes - sorry should of clarified, in sphinx columns created at run time are sometimes called virtual attributes. Your 'd' in the example is a virtual column, it doesnt exist in the index, but you can use it to sort etc.